# How to extract a React key from a js Date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, key, date-fns

I'm building a schedule calendar in React and wondering what's the best way to extract a key from a js `Date` object? I'm already using the date-fns library but haven't seen anything about ids in their documentation.

to be clear, each date only appears once in the list so I'm looking for the fastest way to get a unique key out of a date, without using the object reference.

So far I'm using `date.valueOf()` or `format(date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')` although I feel that might be overkill since it might be recalculated every render.

Comment: Maybe you can use timeStamp as key or ?

Comment: What do you mean? Using the date itself as key?